# Thingspeak: Parse json response with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I would like to create an Alexa skill using Python to use data uploaded by sensors to Thingspeak. The cases where I only use one specific value is quite easy, the response from Thingspeak is the value only. When I want to use several values, in my case to sum up the athmospheric pressure to determine tendencies, teh response is a json object like this:

```
{"channel":{"id":293367,"name":"Weather Station","description":"My first attempt to build a weather station based on an ESP8266 and some common sensors.","latitude":"51.473509","longitude":"7.355569","field1":"humidity","field2":"pressure","field3":"lux","field4":"rssi","field5":"temp","field6":"uv","field7":"voltage","field8":"radiation","created_at":"2017-06-25T07:35:37Z","updated_at":"2018-08-04T12:11:22Z","elevation":"121","last_entry_id":1812},"feeds":
[{"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:11:45Z","entry_id":1713,"field2":"1025.62"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:12:05Z","entry_id":1714,"field2":"1025.58"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:12:25Z","entry_id":1715,"field2":"1025.56"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:12:45Z","entry_id":1716,"field2":"1025.65"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:13:05Z","entry_id":1717,"field2":"1025.58"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:13:25Z","entry_id":1718,"field2":"1025.63"}]
```

I now started with

```
f = urllib.urlopen(link) # Get your data
json_object = json.load(f)

for entry in json_object[0]
  print entry["field2"]
```

The json object is a bit recursive, it is a list containing a list with an element with an array as the value.
Now I am not quite sure how to iterate over the values of the key "field2" in the array. I am quite new to Python and also json. Perhaps anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with json - once the json string parsed by `json.load()`, what you get is a plain python object (usually a dict, sometimes a list, rarely - but this would be legal - a string, int, float, boolean or `None`).

> it is a list containing a list with an element with an array as the value.

Actually it's a `dict` with two keys `"channel"` and `"feeds"`. The first one has another dict for value, and the second a `list` of `dict`s. How to use dicts and lists is extensively documented FWIW

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range

Here the values you're looking for are stored under the "field2" keys of the dicts in the "feeds" key, so what you want is:

```
# get the list stored under the "feeds" key
feeds = json_object["feeds"]

# iterate over the list:
for feed in feeds:
    # get the value for the "field2" key
    print feed["field2"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I just figured it out by myself. This is exactly how it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary. Use key to access the value

**Ex:**

```
json_object = {"channel":{"id":293367,"name":"Weather Station","description":"My first attempt to build a weather station based on an ESP8266 and some common sensors.","latitude":"51.473509","longitude":"7.355569","field1":"humidity","field2":"pressure","field3":"lux","field4":"rssi","field5":"temp","field6":"uv","field7":"voltage","field8":"radiation","created_at":"2017-06-25T07:35:37Z","updated_at":"2018-08-04T12:11:22Z","elevation":"121","last_entry_id":1812},"feeds":
[{"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:11:45Z","entry_id":1713,"field2":"1025.62"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:12:05Z","entry_id":1714,"field2":"1025.58"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:12:25Z","entry_id":1715,"field2":"1025.56"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:12:45Z","entry_id":1716,"field2":"1025.65"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:13:05Z","entry_id":1717,"field2":"1025.58"}, 
 {"created_at":"2018-10-21T18:13:25Z","entry_id":1718,"field2":"1025.63"}]}

for entry in json_object["feeds"]:
    print entry["field2"]
```

**Output:**

```
1025.62
1025.58
1025.56
1025.65
1025.58
1025.63
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was just like expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, it was just like expected.
You have to get the `entries` array from the dict and than iterate over the list of items and print the value to the key `field2`.

```
# Get entries from the response
entries = json_object["feeds"]

# Iterate through each measurement and print value
for entry in entries:
  print entry['field2']
```